# How to add button in PHP Mail function?

Tags: php, html, css, email

I'm trying to insert a button in an anchor tag with an href. I want the user to see a button and not a link

```html
<a href='http://example.com/PhpProject3/reset_passwd.php?key="<?= $email; ?>"&userid="<?= $userid; ?>"' style=' background-color: #4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;'>Click To Reset password</a>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like a button. So whats your question ??

Comment: @shrithi the question is not correct..i think you need the mail to be an html content..and in it there should be a button which links to reset password right?

Comment: Did you tried mail with headers??

Comment: @Shruti check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343915/how-to-add-button-in-php-mail-function/47343946#47343946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML in your mail like this :

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "<a href='http://example.com/PhpProject3/reset_passwd.php?key=".$email."&userid=".$userid."' style=' background-color: #4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;'>Click To Reset password</a>";
$message .= "Other Information ";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
$html .= '<tr><td><a href='.base_url('customer_management/Approve_credit/reject_credit_limit/'.base64_encode($id).'/'.base64_encode('0').'/'.base64_encode($email_result['uidnr_admin'])).' style="background-color: #F32013;border: none;color: white;padding: 10px 20px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; margin-left:20px">Reject</a></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  <a href='http://example.com/PhpProject3/reset_passwd.php?key=".$email."&userid=".$userid."' style=' background-color: #4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;'>
    <button>Click To Reset password</button>
    </a>";
```